# spring mvc json array double quotes converted to &#034;

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, gson

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateItem.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")    
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView updateItem(ModelAndView model) {
                    List<String> list = aspireDAO.getSingleCol("select prod_id from items order by prod_id asc");
                    JsonArray jArray = AspireUtil.toJsonArray(list);
                    model.setViewName("UpdateItem");
            model.addObject("items", jArray);
                    System.out.println(jArray);
            return model;
        }
```

**for jackson support in spring-servlet.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
      <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
          <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
          <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
      </property>
      <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
            <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
          </bean>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

the json array is good in my controller sysout statement. When i check source of the page the json array is printed like this

```
'[&#034;amgc&#034;,&#034;atup&#034;,&#034;ciwy&#034;,&#034;eyqe&#034;,&#034;ijm
```

What could be the possible reason. How to fix it.

### Regards

Aadam

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(jArray);`, and what would you expect instead of `'[&#034;amgc&#034;,&#034;atup&#034;, ...` ?

Comment: the sysout of json array in controller is ["amgc","atup","ciwy","eyqe","ijmj","jein","jyld","lvwe","twox"]

Comment: What I have observed is, if I return jsonArray.toString() I am getting json array, but not on my view, just on a plane page. I want that array on a view, I think @responsebody should not be used in this case. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This is not and ajax call. The url is requested and in return a jsp is called I want json array on that jsp.

Comment: I didn't read all at first time. You put a JsonArray in the model and pass it to a jsp view, correct ? How do you use that in JSP ? BTW, `&#034;` is an entity representation of `"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show the human readable values you should use

```
<c:out value="${items}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

or just

```
${items}
```

The reason why you're seeing this in the first place is that the special chars are encoded as html entities (the stuff you see) which are considered HTML safe, before being added to the output stream. On the other side, all the tags that are used for outputting the value, have a suitable escape attribute that gives the control if the values should be displayed escaped or not. JSTL display has escapeXml set to true by default, tweaking this will fix your issue

Comment: Thankyou so much. Actually I faced this before, and solved it long back. I was scratching my head for long. Anyhow you are life saver. Thanks